# android COSU single app - lock for browser and just one web-app on gadgets

Tags: android, web-applications, tablet, locked, cosu

I'm not experienced with Android. I want to setup some tablets in such a way, that the gadgets are locked to just one web-app. I think it should be somehow locked to a Browser (which in turn should open directly after the launch of the tablet with the login page of the web-app set as default) and the browser should be locked to a particular web-app/ set of urls.

Can somebody recommend tools/ resources or solutions for my purpose?

I am sure the task itself is not a big deal and I am searching for a solution to keep it as simple as possible without investing to much time to learn or to develop a special webView app for that purpose.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/) to set up a device locked on the Chrome browser and configure Chrome to be locked on a single website, the policy JSON below does just that. To set up a device you can follow the [quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/android/management/quickstart).

Here is a policy to lock a device on Chrome and restrict Chrome to stackoverflow.com:

```json
{
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.android.chrome",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "managed_configuration": {
        "URLBlacklist": ["*"],
        "URLWhitelist": ["stackoverflow.com"]
      },
      "lockTaskAllowed": true,
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    }
  ],
  "persistentPreferredActivities": [
    {
      "receiverActivity": "com.android.chrome",
      "actions": [
        "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      ],
      "categories": [
        "android.intent.category.HOME",
        "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "statusBarDisabled": true
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! This seems a good starting point to many applications that need to be deployed in "kiosk" environments. I'll take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try my app WebLock

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simionescu.vlad.weblock

It seems to be exactly what you're looking for, except for the part with the startup. You'll have to first let the system start, then lock the device and as long as it's locked, somebody who doesn't have the password can only see the current domain in WebLock. (The set of URLs will have to be on one domain.)
I don't think you can do the login part in any way. To let the system start you have to have the password, and if a user has the password he can do anything, be it kiosk mode or whatever. So this should be the way to go, an admin has to prepare the device then hand it over to the normal user who then can see only the specified website.