# How do I prevent the Status Bar and Navigation from ever showing?

Tags: java, android, kiosk

Similar questions already exist here, but although what I'm trying to do is quite similar it isn't the same, so please don't mark as a duplicate.

I am building an app to run on a Kiosk therefore I want to prevent users from exiting the app, in order to do this I will need to hide both the status and navigation bars.

I am able to do both but there is always a method which the user can bring them back in which is not the desirable outcome.

So far I have:

- Read on/trialled the properties that can be used in
  `setSystemUiVisibility()`.
- Experimented with `InputMethodManager`
- Looked into different full screen options Immersive, Sticky Immersive
  and Lean back.
- Looked into properties that can be set in the manifest file.
- Browsed through the documentation.
- Googled for similar issues.

The Ideal solution would be one where I don't have to repeat the same setup for every single activity..

Comment: I have a feeling that this is something that Android won't allow for considering this isn't the intended use case?

Comment: Have you tried the Android Management API? See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339245).

Comment: @Fred I am already in the process of giving a shot, seems like the easiest route to go down, I don't like the Ideal of using a third part EMM or creating my own Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems likes the behaviour/functionality i am looking for is covered by what Android refers to as a [Dedicated Device](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu):

> **Dedicated devices**
>
> As an IT admin, you can configure Android 6.0
> Marshmallow and later devices as dedicated devices (previously called
> corporate-owned, single-use, or COSU devices). These are Android
> devices used for a single purpose, such as digital signage, ticket
> printing, point of sale, or inventory management. To use Android
> devices as dedicated devices, you need to develop Android apps that
> your customers can manage.
>
> Your customers can configure dedicated devices:
>
> - To lock a single application to the screen, and hide the Home and
>   Recents buttons to prevent users from escaping the app.
> - To allow multiple applications to appear on the screen, such as a library kiosk
>   with a catalog app and web browser.

Therefore it would be best to utilise this considering it designed for this specific purpose rather than trying to emulate/mimic such behaviour, which so far does not seem that possible anyways.