# Allow access to a single URL Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, kiosk, kiosk-mode

If I have a suite of Android tablets, is it possible that I can have Chrome be the only app that is used on the tablet whilst also locking Chrome to access 1 URL?

We're building a web app for school kids and we want to lock down its use for everything else.

I understand there's a `kiosk` mode that will lock down to a single app, just can't see anything about disabling the ability to navigate to another website.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're better going with [building an webview app](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview).

That way, you can use android's native `kiosk` mode to lock the device into that app, that's actually just a webview to your web app.

Edit: Also, I found out something that could be interesting for your case: [Android's Lock Task Mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode)

From documentation:

> Android can run tasks in an immersive, kiosk-like fashion called lock task mode. You might use lock task mode if you’re developing a kiosk application or a launcher to present a collection of apps. When the system runs in lock task mode, device users typically can’t see notifications, access non-allowlisted apps, or return to the home screen (unless the home screen is allowlisted).

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer because I actually found what you're looking for.

You can setup an application to change the device's policies to lock-on on the Chrome app and then lock Chrome to a single website.

[Here is the full reference of the answer you're looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339245/android-cosu-single-app-lock-for-browser-and-just-one-web-app-on-gadgets)